# Prevent showing I'm using express/NginX

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I made  new server setup where I use NginX and Express (Node.js).

I was doing some tests in online services to try to test/detect possible problems. One of them returned:

```
System Details:
Running on: nginx/1.10.0
Powered by: Express
```

How does this information leak out to public and how can I prevent it?

I would like my server to not reveal the technologies behind the scenes to reduce knowledge about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide nginx version info by adding/ un-commenting `server_tokens off;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` http section.

You can also use nginx to hide/override the `x-powered-by` header

I tend to use [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) for express apps.
If you also use it, which you should be, or something like it you can set any value to the header.

```
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy({ setTo:
    'Love and other drugs'
}));
```

Comment: Thank you! Helmet looks like something I should have!